# Azure web app running PHP (Laravel) on Linux can't connect to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, odbc

I have a php web app on azure and a SQL Server. I'm running Laravel and trying to connect to the SQL Server, but I'm getting the error:

```
This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64
```

If I install the ODBC driver it works but obviously is not an option because when the service restart I'll need to reinstall it every time. So, is there a solution for it ? I mean I've seen it's not possible, only in VM but does that mean we can't have PHP + SQL Server on azure web app ?

Comment: What do you mean when the service restarts you'll need to reinstall it? Restarting an instance doesn't uninstall applications/drivers, etc.

Comment: @Larnu you mean if I install the ODBC driver on a azure php web app once it will always work ? I mean isn't it a sandbox environment which might run in multiple server instance which might mean one of the instances not having the driver ?

Comment: @Larnu: after a push I get "app container will begin restart within 10 seconds.", after that the driver will be missing

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the docker image would restart the ODBC driver would be gone so we need to install it using a startup script.
If you'd like to connect azure web app php to SQL Server setup the environment variables and then:

1. Connect through Web SSH to your Azure Web App
2. Check linux release by running: cat /etc/os-release
3. Use wget to download the correct ODBC driver from here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017
4. Make sure the ODBC driver is in the home folder of your Azure Web App (so it's persistente)
5. Create a startup.sh file on your home folder with the following:

   ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y /home/

   apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
6. Go to your azure web app configuration page and click General Settings
7. Under startup command use "/home/startup.sh"

Now every time the Docker Image reloads it will install the ODBC drivers missing.